# How to get these divs side-by-side while still keeping position:relative and not using float?

Tags: html, css

the only way I've been able to get these side-by-side is by using position:absolute. I need to keep the position as 'relative' for both, and not use any floats. how can this be achieved?

http://jsfiddle.net/tLdsyLwm/1/

HTML

```
<body>
    <section id="wrapper">
        <div id="Div1">1</div>
        <div id="Div2">2</div>
    </section>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body{
    background:skyblue;
}
#wrapper{ 
    width:1000px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#Div1{ 
    position:relative;
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
    width:499px;
    height:200px;
    background:blue;
}

#Div2{ 
    position:relative;
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
    width:499px;
    height:200px;
    background:green;
}
```

Comment: Try using a grid system like bootstrap, suzy, foundation etc.

Comment: you could look at flexbox as well

Comment: @errata those all use float 99% of the time.

Comment: sorry.. what is wrong with float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the newline between those two elements when having an `inline-block` to achieve what you want. Newline will create spaces between them.

**From this:**

```
<body>
    <section id="wrapper">
        <div id="Div1">1</div>
        <div id="Div2">2</div>
    </section>
</body>
```

**To:**

```
<body>
    <section id="wrapper">
        <div id="Div1">1</div><div id="Div2">2</div>
    </section>
</body>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robincarlo84/eeyz0yzk/)

Comment: Wow, thank you, I had no idea that was possible... Awesome fix.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the display:inline-block to display:table-cell. Ex:

```
#Div2{ 
    position:relative;
    vertical-align:top;
    display:table-cell;
    width:499px;
    height:200px;
    background:green;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tLdsyLwm/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

since you already have `inline-block` that means they should go side by side if there is enough room in the parent element.

When you set things to `inline-block` a margin is added to those elements, so technically you have `499 + 499 + someMargin = more than 1000`. try adding a negative right/left margin. This will take the margin away and your total width will be less than or equal to 1000.

http://jsfiddle.net/tLdsyLwm/4/

alternatively, increase the width of the parent element to 1010 or something like that.